# Is a cracked brick sign of a deeper problem

Tags: brick, building

I've just noticed a cracked brick,  and wondered if I could just replace it and do some repointing,  or could suggest another problem?

The cracked brick appears to have a crack in the mortar moving diagonally up a 3 or 4 bricks to the right.  I've included a photo and the brick I'm talking about is 3 bricks up from the left window sill and then 3 in.

My house was built in 1910, and has had its wall ties replaced in the late 70s.

[image]

[better quality picture download link](https://app.box.com/s/qcvv161v6xvjlfmzhxrqgybzbo21mo9o)

Comment: Sorry re-pointing not repainting!

Comment: It looks like there are a few areas that have been repaired in the past and some above the cracked brick need some work. It needs attention but I wouldn't think it is an emergency but should be fixed. A new brick would be the best way and while at it clean up and repoint the upper area. 4 bricks up after looking again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a structual engineer but it's probably the foundation settling a little unevenly. If it was me, I wouldn't be concerned by the couple of cracks you have now but I would certainly keep an eye on it for new cracks, cracks growing longer and cracks going wider.  I'd probably get a professional opinion if it got worse. Keep an eye out for interior cracks too.

Comment: My understanding is that diagonal cracks usually are uneven settling.  But don't take my word for it.